# Can't retrieve source in manifest from Org due to "Error authenticating with the refresh token due to: expired access/refresh token"

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, visualstudiocode

I created a Project with Manifest some time ago and worked on it but today I need to modify some classes but when I try to Retrieve Source in Manifest from Org I hit the following error:

```
Error authenticating with the refresh token due to: expired access/refresh token
```

I even Authorize an Org again and it works but when I try to fetch the code from the Org I hit the same error. Also I navigated to the Org's Setup, checked in Connected Apps OAuth Usage, and for Salesforce CLI the user count it's 1.

Do I need to refresh the Org's token in order to have access again?

Comment: what command do you use? If you are using VsCode build-in thing, try using terminal.
Please copy-paste here command that VsCode is running for retrieve, probably it specifies incorrect username. You can check it in "Output" -> "Salesforce CLI"

Comment: @ytiq I'm using cmd+shift+P and then selecting Retrieve Source in Manifest from Org and all I'm getting on the Output is this:
'20:27:57.124 Starting SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org
Error authenticating with the refresh token due to: expired access/refresh token'

Comment: @JorgeValdés - Can you please authorize org again and make sure the alias you're using is the default one. So that SF will use it for retrieving the metadata.

Comment: and check you .sfdx/sfdx-config.json file to make sure that you use correct alias for the org name

Comment: @ytiq I'm using the default one and I also tried using a new one but I get the same error. I had to create a new Project with Manifest and then I authorize an Org but I named it different, that's the only way I found to retrieve the metadata from SF.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, it is when use the extension on the command palette. Go to the terminal and run:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -x manifest/package.xml
```

Comment: Hi Carlos, welcome to SFSE! No need to sign your posts, it's actually discouraged here.

Answer (score 0):

Reauthorize the Org and then re start your VS Code Application, worked for me.